# Laravel 9 Project Deployed On Plesk Shared host shows the just the main page the other routes not working

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, plesk, shared-hosting

I have a shared host on Plesk and I have upload my Laravel Project on it .
I have put the project in the root folder and change the document root in hosting settings to public folder that belong to my project

When I open the website the first page works fine but when I try to move to another page it gives me an 404 error which mean that my route doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding a

> web.config

file inside the public folder and put the following code in it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```